# Pass Input Parameter to ActionResult MVC 4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following .cshtml

```
    <fieldset>
      <legend></legend>
      <p>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("PlayerList", "Players", new{id = "Id"}, FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Teams, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Id", "Name"),
               "Select a Team", new { id = "ddlTeams" }) <input type="submit" value="Get Player List" />
        }
      </p>
    </fieldset>
```

The DropDownList is filled from some javascript:

```
$("#ddlComps").change(function () {
        var compid = $(this).val();
        $.getJSON("../Players/LoadTeamsByCompId", { compid: compid },
                     function (teamsData) {
                        var select = $("#ddlTeams");
                        select.empty();
                        select.append($('<option/>', {
                            value: 0,
                            text: "Select a Team"
                        }));
                        $.each(teamsData, function (index, itemData) {
                            select.append($('<option/>', {
                                value: itemData.Value,
                                text: itemData.Text
                            }));
                        });
                     });
    });
```

Why is it when I click the submit button, no Id parameter is passed to the ActionResult `PlayerList`?

Comment: Show your action result code.

Comment: @Ryan... ActionResult looks like this: `public ActionResult PlayersList(int id = 0){...}` The methods is called but id is always 0.

Comment: Are you including the [HTTPPOST] attribute?

Comment: @Ryan..,Yeas I am using the attribute: `[HttpPost]public ActionResult PlayersList(int id = 0){...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said your ActionResult looks like (notice the 's')

```
public ActionResult PlayersList(int id = 0){...}
```

But your BeginForm action is

```
PlayerList
```

So my bet is that you are posting to the wrong action.

You also have to set the field `name` attribute to the same you expect on your action.

Comment: My bad - just a typo. Where do I set the name attribute?

Comment: You are using `@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Teams...` so it already generated the field with a name, it must match the action's parameter name

Comment: Thanks so much @BrunoLM, I changed it to: `@Html.DropDownList("Id", ...)` and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Specify a name parameter on your DropDownList that indicates that the value is for the "ID" parameter. name="id" and that should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you watch the network requests from your browser's debug console you will see that your form is posting `Teams` but your action is expecting `id` which never is sent so defaults to 0. It's not being sent because you don't have a field named `id`.

Change your action to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PlayersList(int teams = 0)
{
    ...
}
```